# array Xpath 'name' 'value'

Tags: html, xpath

from this html code I have to extract two values, two separate fields: the first  in 'name' and the second  in 'value'

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span><strong>CPU &amp; Dissipatore&nbsp;</strong></span>
</td>
<td>
<span>Intel i7-11700K Dissipatore a Liquido 240mm&nbsp;</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Xpath code:

```
array(
    'name' => ".//table//tr//td[1]",
    'value' => ".//table//tr//td[2]",
),
```

So I get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
//tr//td/span
```

### Output

```
CPU & Dissipatore 
Intel i7-11700K Dissipatore a Liquido 240mm
```

Answer (score 0):

Name/value pairs in XPath (3.1) would be maps not arrays so in XPath 3.1 you can use e.g.

```
map {
  'name' : //table//tr//td[1]/string(),
  'value' : //table//tr//td[2]/string()
}
```

[Online sample](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=map%20%7B%0A%20%20%27name%27%20%3A%20%2F%2Ftable%2F%2Ftr%2F%2Ftd%5B1%5D%2Fstring%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%27value%27%20%3A%20%2F%2Ftable%2F%2Ftr%2F%2Ftd%5B2%5D%2Fstring%28%29%0A%7D&input=%3Ctable%3E%0A%3Ctbody%3E%0A%3Ctr%3E%0A%3Ctd%3E%0A%3Cspan%3E%3Cstrong%3ECPU%20%26amp%3B%20Dissipatore%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3Ctd%3E%0A%3Cspan%3EIntel%20i7-11700K%20Dissipatore%20a%20Liquido%20240mm%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A&input-type=HTML).